# Creating PopupWindow from IME: BadTokenException

Tags: keyboard, popupwindow, ime

I'm trying to make a popup window appear from an IME service (an onscreen keyboard) that has no activity.  When I call popUp.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.CENTER, 0, -100) I get a "Windowmanager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not valid."  I know it's a little unusual to open a popup window from a service with no associated activity -- is it possible?

Here is my code:

```
public void initiatePopupWindow()
{
    try {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_layout,null);

        // create a 300px width and 470px height PopupWindow
        popUp = new PopupWindow(layout, 300, 470, true);
        popUp.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.CENTER, 0, -100);


        Button cancelButton = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.popup_cancel_button);
        cancelButton.setOnClickListener(inputView.cancel_button_click_listener);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem -- I was attempting to draw a popup using a layout and use the same layout as the parent.  The solution is to set the parent to another view.  I found it's also import to make sure the view has been created before creating the popup (e.g., by using a handler/runnable).

```
public void initiatePopupWindow()
{
    try {
        Log.i("dotdashkeyboard","initiatePopupWindow (from IME service)");
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_layout,null);

        // create a 300px width and 470px height PopupWindow
        popUp = new PopupWindow(layout, 300, 470, false);
        popUp.showAtLocation(inputView, Gravity.CENTER, 0, -100);

        Button cancelButton = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.popup_cancel_button);
        cancelButton.setOnClickListener(inputView.cancel_button_click_listener);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```